# Placeholder text in an unfilled (empty) text box on an Access form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

How can I add "placeholder" text to a Text Box in an Access form?

Before the user has typed anything into the text box I want it to display something like

Name: `[Please enter the right name]`

and then when the user enters some value the text box should show that instead.

Comment: Is there any way to insert a placeholder in a textfild of MS access Form

Comment: What type of value is intended for that text box?

Comment: It's like Placeholder>>"Please enter the right name" and value is Name

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `.Format` property, for text values it will be like this:

```
@;"Please enter the right name"
```

Comment: But it will add as the default value ...that doesn't sound like palceholder

Answer (score 0):

And if you would like to use like a really placeholder, use conditional formatting. Set the default text color value to gray and if the value is not a "" (empty) set the color to black.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to combine the date and placeholder
use format as short Date

and in events vba

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
If IsNull(Me.VDate) Then
Me.VDate.Format = "@;Date[Blue]"
Else
Me.VDate.Format = "Short Date"
End If
End Sub

Private Sub VDate_AfterUpdate()
If IsNull(Me.VDate) Then
Me.VDate.Format = "@;Date[Blue]"
Else
Me.VDate.Format = "Short Date"
End If
End Sub
```